# Error in Load Topbeat Index Template in Elasticsearch

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, topbeat

I am getting error when i load topbeat template
`curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_template/topbeat' -d@topbeat.template.json`

Error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}
```